# Change the DIV background-color permanently

Tags: html, css, sass

How can I change the background color of a div tag permanently once it is clicked.
Tried the following code :

```
div {
 min-height: 50px;
 background-color: yellow;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 padding: 10px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;

   &:active {
      background-color: red;
    }
 }
```

But with this the background color is restored to previous one after the click is released.
Is there a way to do this with SCSS  and html alone?

```html
<div class="div">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want pure CSS/SCSS approach, you can do it using transition delay.
First of all you set transition of 0s, and a delay of some higher value (like 100000s). Now when you active the element, change the transition to 0s without delay so that it changes it's color immediately, now since there is a huge delay it becomes almost permanent. (but after the delay time that you set is over, it would become back to it's initial state)

```
div {
 min-height: 50px;
 background-color: yellow;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 padding: 10px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 transition: background-color 0s 100000s;

   &:active {
      background-color: red;
      transition: background-color 0s;
    }
 }
```

```css
div {
 min-height: 50px;
 background-color: yellow;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 padding: 10px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 transition: background-color 0s 100000s;
 }
 
 div:active {
    background-color: red;
    transition: background-color 0s;
 }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <div class="div" id="myDiv">
   <p>Hello</p>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 div {
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  }
```

JS

```
 let myDiv=document.getElementById("myDiv");

 myDiv.addEventListener('click',()=>{
   myDiv.style.background='red';
 })
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the OP asked for pure HTML and SCSS solution. Not using js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).